# Android Find Phone App

Tags: android

I am playing around and I am trying to make a Android find phone app like the onces in the market place.  if someone text my phone "beep" I want the phone to make a loud sound and if the phone is on silent i still want the sounds. I was thinking to use a alarm but the alarm does not make sound.  can someone give me some

Answer (score 0):

you are right... try out to invoke media player. because Media player always work immaterial to phone ringer. Something like this http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_playing_mediamp3_on_the_emulator-t156.html

Comment: no good! if its on silent it does not play ad if no songs no good.  I need to find out how to set off a alarm